# nested loop don't go inside each element c#

Tags: c#, matrix

Here is a part of what I wrote:

```
    double[,] visualmatrix = new double[3, m_descriptor.visualword.Length];

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m_descriptor.length; j++)
        {
          visualmatrix[i, j] = (m_descriptor.visualword[j].tf) * (m_descriptor.visualword[j].idf);
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(visualmatrix[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

What I want for visual matrix in this case, is to fill visualmatrix[0,0] till visualmatrix[2,29] since m_descriptor.length is 29.
But what is done that it fills just the first element of each i: visualmatrix[0,0],visualmatrix[1,0],visualmatrix[2,0].

Comment: `m_descriptor.visualword.Length` and `m_descriptor.length` is a different, isn't it?

Comment: No sorry I edit it, it is the same

Comment: Can you show how you initiate `m_descriptor`

Comment: Use the debugger to check the value of m_descriptor.length. It seems to be 1.

Comment: They're still different: `m_descriptor.visualword.Length`  on line 1 vs `m_descriptor.length`on line 5

Comment: I am using TopSurf, m_descriptor = TOPSURF_DESCRIPTOR.ConvertDescriptor(data.Descriptor);

Comment: multi-dimensional arrays suck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I consider, you have missed `.visualword` in for statement. Change `j<m_descriptor.length` to `j<m_descriptor.visualword.length`

```
double[,] visualmatrix = new double[3, m_descriptor.visualword.Length];

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<m_descriptor.visualword.length; j++)
    {
      visualmatrix[i, j] = (m_descriptor.visualword[j].tf) * (m_descriptor.visualword[j].idf);
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(visualmatrix[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```